# Create maven dependency instead of .jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

Is there a way where I can take an existing java project (it's an automation framework) and actually export it out in a way that another project can consume it using the maven GAV instead of having to add it as an external jar?

I was able to create a jar of the framework project and then tested adding the jar to a 2nd project and all that works fine. I really would just prefer to be able to reference the framework project as a maven dependency in the pom instead of having to add the jar. I also think this will be easier when it comes to making updates to the framework and having the consuming projects just update the version of the maven dependency in the pom.

Of course I could be way off with my thinking here. I'm primarily in the c# world where I can just export my project out as a nuget package that gets consumed easily so that's what I'm used to.

Thanks!

Comment: You can `mvn install` the artifact into your local (or a remote) maven repository, and then add it as a dependency in another project. I typically package a compiled jarfile for that

Comment: If you have a company (maven) repository, you can deploy the jar to the repository, so that it can be used eg. when building on jenkins, see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: Gotcha...so I should have some place locally to store the jar (maven repo) and then as long as any projects have access to that repo they can just reference the maven gav?